# How to check when a async function has completed its execution through promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have an async function which is being called by another function. I want to perform some action once the async function has completed its execution. I am trying to use promises to do this. I think I am going wrong somewhere in my usage of promises. Here is the code I have:

```
function foo(){
setTimeout(()=>console.log("hello world"),1000)
}

function bar(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
  resolve(foo())
  })
}

bar().then(()=>console.log("foo has completed"))
```

The console prints "foo has completed" even before the async has completed its execution.

Comment: `foo()` returns BEFORE it is done with its timer because `setTimeout()` is asynchronous and non-blocking.  The problem is in `foo()`.  Promises or `resolve()` have no magic powers to somehow know when an async operation in them is done.  You have to ONLY call `resolve()` when the asynchronous operation is actually done.  You're calling it before the async operation is done.  Thus, the promise triggers before the async operation is done.

Answer (score 2):

Calling resolve is something you should do yourself. Since foo returns immediately, your promise also get resolved immediately. However, you could do something like below if that fulfills your requirement.

```js
function foo(resolve) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("hello world");
    resolve();
  }, 1000)
}

function bar() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    foo(resolve)
  })
}

bar().then(() => console.log("foo has completed"))
```

Comment: This is a weird way to program with promises. foo() should just return its own promise.

Answer (score 1):

If you spend some time looking at javascript you will notice that all async functions have some mechanism for letting you know when they are done. This is typically callbacks or promises, but sometimes other things like events.

Your function `foo()` performs an async operation, but offers not way to alert the caller or anyone else when it's done. That's what is causing your problem, and there's no good way to fix it without changing `foo()`. Here are some things you can do.

## Have foo call a callback

You could change `foo()` to call a callback when it's finished. Then it might look like this:

```
 function foo(cb){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("hello world")
        cb(null, true) // callbacks offen pass an error as their first arg or null if there's no error

    },1000)
}
```

With that, `bar()` can call it passing a callback and then either fire a callback or return a promise. Here we'll return a promise and wire it all together:

```js
function foo(cb){
    console.log("foo called")
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("foo's timeout finished")
        cb(null, true)

    },1000)
}
    
function bar(){
    console.log("car called")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        foo((err, res) => {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            resolve( "foo finished with " + res)
        })
    })
}

bar().then((result)=>console.log("bar has finish and returned: ", result))
```

## Or have Foo return a promise

If `foo()` just returned a promise that resolved when it was finished, it would all be easier because then `bar()` could just return then promise or call `.then()` and return that if it need to process the results:

```js
function foo(cb) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("hello world")
    resolve(true)
  }, 1000))
}

function bar() {
  return foo().then(res => "foo finished with: " + res)
}

bar().then((result) => console.log("bar has finish and returned: ", result))
```

Comment: 2nd option > 1st option.  Promisifying at the lowest level practical is preferred.

Comment: @jfriend00 agreed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be like this

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("hello world");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function bar() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(foo());
  });
}

bar().then(() => console.log("foo has completed"));
```

Comment: Why mark a function async if you don't use await in it

Comment: No reason to create a new promise in `bar()`.  You can just do `return foo()` inside of `bar()`.  And, no reason to use `async` keyword at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `setTimeout()` call in the `resolve` call. This should fix it:

```
function foo(resolve){
setTimeout(()=> { 
  console.log("hello world");
  resolve()
 },1000)
}

function bar(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    return foo(resolve)
  })
}

bar().then(()=>console.log("foo has completed"))
```

Comment: This is a weird way to program with promises.  `foo()` should just return its own promise.

Comment: @jfriend00, functions are the first class citizens and could be passed around any way you want. I think you're applying personal patterns that are not related to the problem domain. You can look at the `resolve` param as a `callback`, and that may change your prospective

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, but it's not common to pass around a reference to `resolve` and not recommended either.  That's why the promise specification doesn't have deferred objects, only promises with the promise executor.  Anyone who programs with promises regularly would tell you that `foo` should just return its own promise here.  That's the cleaner promise design.  Yes, all of design is an opinion, but when most people educated on the topic would have the same opinion about a design, that's a common and accepted design pattern.

Comment: Looking at it as callback means you're mixing promises and callbacks which is a bad design decision.  It just complicates everything.  Good promise design promisifies async operations at the lowest level and then uses only promise flow control management.  I rather doubt you're going to win any argument that this is a preferred design and that's what my first comment is about.

Comment: I agree with @jfriend00 - it's a little strange although not *that* much different than passing a callback to `foo`. The real difficulty comes in a more realistic scenario where you wanted to account for the possibility that `foo` could have an error. So then you would have to pass both `resolve` and `reject` functions into `foo`. But that's not the way most callback-based functions work -- they prefer the `callback(err, result)` pattern. Which leaves you with a `foo` that doesn't work the way most people would expect it to, which leads to bugs.

Comment: I am fine with promise based flows, but it's not always true that you can freely wrap anything around that. One of the cases is consuming 3rd parties, where it just takes a callback. Notion of a callback makes this agnostic to the nature of specific underlaying mechanism of consumption, and is higher level than just promise based approaches

Comment: @Mark Meyer, right, success and error handling is important aspect, but i think it's a different concern in this case

Comment: How is a callback a "higher level" than a promise implementation.  Are you arguing that callbacks are always better than promises or that interfaces should not be promise based?  And, that the present and future of asynchronous operations in Javascript isn't promises and the tools for managing promises?  If so you're living in the wrong decade.  Why don't you just edit your answer into a better solution rather than argue against the use of promises?

Comment: in a way that it is abstract. And I am not arguing that callbacks are always better, but i am not a supporter of over promisifying either

Comment: In this case, a plain callback is "lower level" than a promise, not "higher level".  It's a lower level of functionality.  I think you got your terminology backwards.  Still not sure why you're defending your implementation rather than just editing your answer into a better answer (which is one goal of my comments).  Or perhaps I should just write my own answer.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I think I'll just refer you to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-_and_low-level